# xcode 4 second target?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, xcode4

i want to add a second target in xcode 4. Tis second target should use the same classes files and xibs. (appdelegate, main.m, mainwindow.xib,...) but the second target should have a own info.plist file and own app-icons.

But i have no idea how i can do this in xdode 4. In xcode 3 it was so easy just add a new target.

i have tried: 
- duplicating target (but then it has the same plist )
- adding a new target (but then it has own appdelegate files)

Can anybody help me with this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After duplicationg target in you can change Info.plist setting to your new plist file in Target Editor>Build Settings>Packaging